# install ubuntu windows and Chrome operating system together

Tags: operating-systems

Can you install 3 operating systems on one desktop hard drive I wish to install Ubuntu, Windows 8 and Chrome OS can someone help me with that please

Answer (score 0):

> Can you install 3 operating systems on one desktop hard drive

Yes

> can someone help me

Probably also yes.

You will probably need to set your BIOS to UEFI and partition the disk with GPT, so windows doesn't shit.
I would partition from ubuntu live env, giving 512mb to boot/efi part; first 2/3 of drive to linux (ext4); next 1/3 to chrome (whatever it's preferred FS is) and the final third to windows (formatted to NTFS)
Install windows first, you may need to select "advanced" drive options at the installer. It won't recognise the non-windows partitions so should install itself at the end of the drive without buggering anything up.
Then install chrome to it's part, it should be aware of all the partitions. If given the option "install along side existing OS" and "do not install boot loader to MBR"

Then install linux with a boot loader. GRUB2. This should tidy everything up and give you the startup menu to choose which OS.

Comment: Hi thanks is there any step by step instructions for this online which I could follow?